# Rails: Friendship join table clarification

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently working on my first project and am trying to add "friending" to my app. However, I'm having a little trouble grasping the concept of the friendships model, since attributes that don't seem to exist in my database seem to just work.

I have my model and database columns listed below. I understand that this is a join table, but in the user model where do `friends`, `requested_friends`, and `pending friends` come from if they don't exist in the `friendships` table? Is it because it is a virtual join table so that I could just add whatever columns I need without having to migrate them?

Also, the tutorial eventually does `@user.pending_friends.each` even though that column doesn't exist in my `users` table. I'm pretty confused on this part.

Currently I'm going through this brief tutorial: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=16760

Here are my files:

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
...
has_many :friendships, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships, :conditions => "status = 'accepted'"
has_many :requested_friends, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend, :conditions => "status = 'requested'", :order => :created_at
has_many :pending_friends, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend, :conditions => "status = 'pending", :order => :created_at
```

end

friendship model

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :friend_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
end
```

schema

```
create_table "friendships", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "friend_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
  t.string   "password_digest"
  t.string   "remember_token"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgotten to migrate since you don't have `status` column in your schema. Associations you're referring is bound to `friend_id` key that *exist* in friendships table. Last 2 associations is just using foreign key defined for `belongs_to :friend`. Please have a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-source). I guess such associations can work without actual attribute if this is what you meant, you just don't get `condition:` functionality here and all 3 last associations will return same values.